# Not able to set initial dates using react day picker and Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form, react-query, react-day-picker

I am using Next.js, React Query and React Day Picker with React Hook Form.

I am fetching some dates from an endpoint using React Query and I want to set these dates as the initial dates that are picked. If I navigate around the site and go to the page the dates show up as selected. However, if I refresh the page no dates appear. I have to navigate to another page and navigate back to see the selected dates.

```
  const {
    data: initialDatesTest,
    error,
    isLoading,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["dates"],
    queryFn: getDates,
  });
  async function getDates() {
    const response = await fetch("/api/dates-to-exclude");
    const data = await response.json();
    const parsedExcludedDates = data.excludedDates.PartyExcludeDates.map(
      (dateString: string) => new Date(dateString)
    );

    return parsedExcludedDates;
  }

const initialDays: Date[] = initialDatesTest || [];
const [days, setDays] = useState<Date[] | undefined>(initialDays);


      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="DayPicker"
        render={({ field }) => (
          <DayPicker
            mode="multiple"
            min={1}
            selected={days}
            onSelect={setDays}
            footer={footer}
            disabled={{ before: new Date() }}
            numberOfMonths={1}
          />
        )}
      />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `initialDatesTest` is undefined before the data has been fetched, and the initial value is only set on the first render. You want to call `setDays` in the `onSuccess` of `useQuery`. Something like

```js
const {
  data: initialDatesTest,
  error,
    isLoading,
} = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["dates"],
  queryFn: getDates,
});

async function getDates() {
  const response = await fetch("/api/dates-to-exclude");
  const data = await response.json();
  const parsedExcludedDates = data.excludedDates.PartyExcludeDates.map(
    (dateString: string) => new Date(dateString)
  );

  setDates(parsedExcludedDates); // update state to reflect what was returned from server.

  return parsedExcludedDates;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. I am getting error Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'onSuccess' does not exist in type 'UseQueryOptions<any, Error, any, string[]>'.ts(2769). It doesn't prevent the application from running, but it also doesn't resolve the issue. When I refresh I still don't see the dates until I navigate away and come back

Comment: Ahh, you are probably on a different version. So you'll have to update you're getDates fn to handle that I believe. I'll update my code to reflect those changes.

Comment: Thanks very much! I’ll only be able to try it out later but I’ll definitely respond once I have.